# who to multiple node load with node_load function in drupal 6?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

how is it possible to load a group of nods using [Node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/6) functionality while not utilizing any link of loops ?
and send specified `"NIDs"` list to the `nodeload` .
while the Node_load function doesn't accept an `array` of `NID's` .

and if you know better function like [node_load_multiple](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7) in drupal 7 please recomend me .

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function in D6. And even if you write one yourself, you will still have call the load hooks etc. on each node separately.

See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4416/performant-way-to-load-many-complete-node-objects